# NP-hard problems which are easy on average

Tags: computational-complexity, np-complete

Are there any known NP-hard problems that are easy on average as per the definition of average-case complexity by Levin?

Answer (score 1):

How about this: Recognize strings of $2n$ bits such that at least one of the first $n$ bits is $1$ *or* the last $n$ bits describe a satisfiable Boolean formula.

(If that is not an example, you may have to remind me exactly what Levin's definition is).